# Why this CSS font-face code does not load the font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have the written the following code in CSS for it to load the fonts. The path are double checked, they are fine, but I do not know why it does not load them up. it worked until quite several days ago. Now, it does not work. Here is the written code:

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'yekan';
    src: url('fonts/WebYekan.eot?#') format('eot'),
        url('fonts/WebYekan.ttf') format('eot'), 
        url('fonts/WebYekan.woff') format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in your browser dev console and looked for the request/response?

Comment: hi , yes i checked , but not work and not found

Comment: Please check url fonts file path is proper or not. Like this fonts/WebYekan.eot.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

You were referencing the wrong format to the wrong font files. Fixed it below:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yekan';
src: url('fonts/WebYekan.eot?#') format('eot'),
    url('fonts/WebYekan.ttf') format('truetype'), 
    url('fonts/WebYekan.woff') format('woff');
```

}

Comment: Your website works just fine, on my browser with the noted font face. Make sure u clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

this may work

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'yekan';
src: url('fonts/WebYekan.eot?#') format('eot'),
url('fonts/WebYekan.ttf') format('truetype'), 
url('fonts/WebYekan.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- check the network tab to see if these files are being referenced
- if you need these fonts so bad then get a local copy and reference them
- need not reference .eot font unless you are using IE